# Parse.com Query if String is Contained in Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, filter, parse-platform

Working with recipes and I would like to query (search) based off of items in the recipe rather than the recipe names.

For example, multiple items may contain Chicken. I want to be able to search Chicken and see the Recipe Names that contain Chicken in the recipe.

Here's what I have tried:

```
- (void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
     PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
     NSArray * ingredientArray = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
     [query whereKey:searchTerm containedIn:ingredientArray];

     [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else
        {
            [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
            [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

}
```

This code returns nothing and I get no errors.

Having difficulty figuring out the right way to set up the query.

Should this be solved as a query within a query?

Meaning:

Query through ingredients first, and then query on that to display the recipe name based on the previous query of recipes that contain the searchTerm.

Comment: Please don't make us guess. What problem are you having? What happens with the code you posted?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misusing the `[query whereKey:containedIn:]` method. This is used to query for all PFObjects where the object for the key you specify is contained in the array you provide. Unless you made a new key for every recipe item, this won't work for your purposes, because none of your objects have a "Chicken" key, for instance.

First, I suggest you use a `RecipeIngredient` class in Parse with the following fields:

- Pointer(Recipe) recipe //pointer to its `Recipe` object
- Number amount //how much of unit
- String unit //cup, gram, etc.
- String ingredient //milk, flour, etc.

Now, you can simply query the `RecipeIngredient` class like so:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:"RecipeIngredient"];
[query whereKey:"ingredient" equalTo:searchTerm];
[query includeKey:"recipe"]; //Fetches the Recipe data via the pointer
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *recipeIngredientObjects, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         NSArray *recipes = [recipeIngredientObjects valueForKey:@"recipe"];
         //update table data as needed
     } else {
         // Log details of the failure
         NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. I dug a lot more into this last night and what I discovered is that the searchTerm has to match word-for-word what is in the array. So if I have "1 cup of flour", I have to type all of that in. Ideally I'd like to search just for flour and get the result.

Comment: Answer edited to show how to setup Parse to be able to search for specific ingredient names

Comment: @LukeIrvin Did you find solution to this? I am also having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem last year sometime so I thought I would share the answer.

```
    [query whereKey:@"ingredient" matchesRegex:searchTerm modifiers:@"i"];
```

That should do it for you. That helps with the case sensitivity.